# How to fix 'Access Denied' while deleting empty S3 Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've noticed some Elastic Beanstalk is drawing about $20 to $30 every month on my AWS account and it turns out it is an empty S3 bucket.

I tried deleting it but it returns "Access Denied" error.

[image: Access Denied]

I also tried to use life cycle to remove it, but it also didn't work. Here is how I set up the life cycle:

[image: Life Cycle]

I set it to remove 1 day after creation

[image]

Comment: You need to look elsewhere for the $20-$30... It's not coming from an empty bucket.  You have an Elastic Beanstalk environment actually running, the bucket is just its configuration.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I never set up an EB.

Comment: Try to delete the elastic beanstalk application from the console

Comment: @tal it will return "access denied" message.

Comment: Ate you using the same user as the one who created it? If you do than your lady chance is aws support

Comment: @tal No I created it myself. I actually got to sit down with an AWS engineer and he was puzzled too. Now this is taken by an AWS support and I am not sure how and when it would be resolved...was hoping to find a solution if someone already struggled with this before.

Comment: i faced same issue , just go to  bucket policy section , and remove completely bucket policy and try to delete bucket now , it should work

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Check the bucket policy on the S3 bucket. The bucket name seems to be the standard bucket that beanstalk creates to store your application versions, logs etc. To prevent accidental deletion of the bucket, the bucket policy denies delete permission. You can update the permissions on the S3 bucket policy to allow delete from your root account. Most likely your bucket policy currently does not allow deletion of the bucket. Then you will be able to delete the bucket.

Read more about S3 bucket permissions here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/EditingBucketPermissions.html

Comment: Yes I have all the permissions set to Me, Authenticated User, aero.windwalker(which is my account), and Everyone. Still doesn't work. D:

Comment: I am not talking about the permission your IAM user or root account has. Check your S3 bucket policy. Right click on the bucket in the S3 console, select properties and in the Permissions section of the properties pane, select "Edit bucket policy". I think you will find a deny on DeleteBucket there.

Comment: **"Most likely your bucket policy currently does not allow deletion of the bucket"** - Right on the mark. Saved my day!

Comment: I actually had to remove the section that denied root delete permission from the JSON.

Comment: Saved my day too! I'm surprised why they can't just provide the GUI instead of the edition a JSON? bucket policy file instead. No wonder they offer a free trial period of 1 year, just to silently charge fee after the trial.

Comment: Also, if anybody is not able to edit and save the policy JSON document, go ahead and delete that policy document for the s3 bucket. then you'll be able to delete.

Answer (score 78):

Elastic beanstalk added this restriction automatically as it creates the bucket. To remove it you will first have to empty the bucket out.

Once done, select the **bucket --> Properties --> Permissions --> Edit bucket 
policy**.

[image]

You will now see the permissions Elastic Beanstalk automatically added to that bucket. Scroll to where you find the **"Action": "s3:DeleteBucket"**, above that Change **"Effect": "Deny" to "Effect": "Allow"**

Once done, save change and delete the bucket.

[image]

Comment: This is great and works. Though the thread above gives the reason and solution. I support this because it is short and sweet.

Comment: This saved me a lot of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

By default, Elastic Beanstalk set some policies on your bucket that prevents the delete operation on the bucket to prevent accidental deletion of the bucket.

I highlighted the operation in red in the image below.

**Step to delete the bucket**:

- Click on the **bucket name**
- Click on the **Permissions tab** between Properties and Management tab
- Click on the **Bucket Policy** tab
- Once you are in the bucket policy tab, click the **delete** button on the
  policy

[image]

Once complete, you go back to the list of the buckets and try to delete the bucket now.

DONE

Happy Coding

Answer (score 18):

This is Elastic beanstalk resection to save your accidental deletion. you can solve this issues by following 2 steps.

1. Grantee permission to upload and delete
2. Edit bucket policy by `bucket => Properties => Permissions => Edit bucket policy` and set allow `"Effect": "Allow"` from `"Effect": "Deny"`

Check below screenshot for more help.

**Permission SCreenshot:**

[image]

**Bucket Policy**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Very short and simple approach would be (if you are sure that you no longer require the bucket) is to remove the bucket policy and then try to delete the bucket. Works in all cases. As the bucket is created by Elastic Beanstalk and configured policy will not allow any changes/delete by other users. Removing policy will allow you to perform action.

Comment: This is a smart solution if this is allowed in the scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

I also came across the same error while deleting the bucket created by EBS "Access Denied" because by default EBS denies DELETE operation on s3 bucket create by it as it is used by EBS for storing logs of application any other pieces of information.
To delete it you have to change the bucket's policy 
Steps:- **Bucket => Properties => Permissions => Bucket Policy** edit the bucket policy where "Action": "s3:DeleteBucket" change the **"Effect": "Deny" to "Effect": "Allow"**

Answer (score 2):

The bucket can be deleted only in the following 3 steps:

1. Select the bucket to be deleted then click on Permission section in opened drawer window
2. Click on Bucket Policy button
3. Replace `Deny` word with `Allow` in the object that has `"Action": "s3:Deletebucket"` line then click on Save button

Thereafter you can delete the bucket.

Figure for step 1:

[image]

Figure for step 2:

[image]

Figure for step 3:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

go to buckets--> permissions --> click on edit bucket policy and then
then delete the policy
then you can easily able to delete bucket